# AEM: How to get administrative resource resolver, since getAdministrativeResourceResolver(Map<String,Object> authenticationInfo) is deprecated?

Tags: java, aem, sling

I have to get administrative prevailed `org.apache.sling.api.resource.ResourceResolver`.

But the API, `ResourceResolverFactory.getAdministrativeResourceResolver(Map<String,Object> authenticationInfo)` is depricated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution by @Dileepa would work, but definitely not a good practice to hardcode passwords and also, its always good to prevent over-use of administrative resourceresolvers/sessions.

Take a look at the implementation mentioned [here](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/service-authentication.html#implementation) in sling docs.

Comment: According to your suggestion, changed the code a little. Can you please validate it?

Comment: :) yep, this would work fine. I had implemented a similar code in one of my projects.

Comment: yes, this would be the recommended approach using ServiceUserMapper, here is a detailed working implementation of that: https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/querying-experience-manager-sling.html

Answer (score 3):

We have added the following configuration:

```
\apps\qwerty\configs\config\org.apache.sling.serviceusermapping.impl.ServiceUserMapperImpl.xml


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="sling:OsgiConfig"
    user.default="admin"
    user.mapping="[com.adobe.granite.oauth.server=oauthservice,com.adobe.granite.oauth.server:authentication-handler=admin,com.day.cq.cq-search-suggest=suggestionservice,com.adobe.cq.social.cq-social-scoring:utility-reader=admin,com.adobe.cq.social.cq-social-commons-oauth:user-reader=admin,com.adobe.cq.social.cq-social-calendar:ugc-writer=admin,com.adobe.cq.social.cq-social-forum:ugc-reader=admin,com.adobe.cq.social.cq-social-group:user-admin=admin,org.apache.sling.scripting.core:workflow-launcher=admin,com.adobe.cq.social.cq-social-storage:ugc-writer=admin,com.adobe.cq.social.cq-social-messaging:utility-reader=admin,com.adobe.cq.social.cq-social-commons-oauth:ugc-writer=admin,com.adobe.cq.social.cq-social-messaging:ugc-writer=admin,com.adobe.cq.social.cq-social-journal:ugc-writer=admin,com.adobe.cq.social.cq-social-forum:workflow-launcher=admin,com.adobe.cq.social.cq-social-commons:utility-reader=admin,com.adobe.cq.social.cq-social-commons:user-reader=admin,com.adobe.cq.social.cq-social-console:communities-user-admin=admin,com.adobe.cq.social.cq-social-ugcbase:utility-reader=admin,com.adobe.cq.social.cq-social-as-provider:ugc-writer=admin,com.adobe.cq.social.cq-social-blog:ugc-writer=admin,com.adobe.cq.social.cq-social-forum:ugc-writer=admin,com.adobe.cq.social.cq-social-ugcbase:ugc-writer=admin,com.adobe.cq.social.cq-social-commons:ugc-writer=admin,com.adobe.cq.social.cq-social-commons:workflow-launcher=admin,com.adobe.cq.social.cq-social-commons-oauth:user-admin=admin,com.adobe.cq.social.cq-social-messaging:user-reader=admin,com.adobe.cq.social.cq-social-handlebars:utility-reader=admin,com.adobe.cq.social.cq-social-tally:ugc-writer=admin]"/>
```

Or you may configure it using `/sysem/console/configMgr` for `Apache Sling Service User Mapper Service`:

[image: Apache Sling Service User Mapper Service]

And now to get `ResourceResolver` service we need to run the following method:

```
resolverFactory.getServiceResourceResolver(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a user in AEM with right privileges.
Use the following code, with `username` and `password` of user which are externalized. The `password` is protected by AEM's default crypto support.

```
@Component(immediate = true, metatype = true, label = "Configuration Details")
@Service(value = { MyResourceResolver.class })
@Properties({
    @Property(label = "Username", name = "username", description = "Username"),
    @Property(label = "Password", name = "password", description = "Password for the above user (Use crypto support)"),
})
public class MyResourceResolver {       
    @Reference
    private ResourceResolverFactory resourceFact;

    @Reference
    private CryptoSupport cryptoSupport;

    private String username;
    private String password;

    public ResourceResolver getUserResourceResolver() throws LoginException{
        Map<String,Object> authenticationInfo = new HashMap<>(2);
        authenticationInfo.put(ResourceResolverFactory.USER, username);
        String unprotectedPass;
        try {
            unprotectedPass = cryptoSupport.unprotect(password);
        } catch (CryptoException e) {
            unprotectedPass = password;
            log.error(e.getMessage());
        }
        authenticationInfo.put(ResourceResolverFactory.PASSWORD, unprotectedPass.toCharArray());
        return resourceFact.getResourceResolver(authenticationInfo);
    }

    @Activate
    protected void activate(Map<String, Object> mapCreated) {
        log.info("Configuration Map");
        username = mapCreated.get("username").toString();
        password = mapCreated.get("password").toString();
    }

    @Modified
    protected void modified(Map<String, Object> mapModified) {
        log.info("Configuration Modified");
        username = mapModified.get("username").toString();
        password = mapModified.get("password").toString();
    }
}
```